# Insert row from one linked table to another

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have three tables in Access: One linked to Excel, one linked to MySQL, and a local table called LastQuery with a single row and column. I use a VBA query in a form with a timer to select data from the Excel table and insert it into the MySQL table. At the same time, I update the `dtmInsertedTime` of the last record that I inserted to LastQuery (into the row titled `last`), so that the next time the form timer ticks, it will continue from the next record and continue until it has inserted every record. My code is simple, but I am getting errors and can't get it to work as I described. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblevent (vchrFacility, intWorkCell, intStn, intEventCode) SELECT vchrFacility, intWorkCell, intStn, intEventCode from excelTblEvent where dtmInsertedTime > LastQuery.Last"
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE LastQuery, excelTblEvent SET LastQuery.Last = excelTblEvent.dtmInsertedTime"
End Sub
```

**EDIT :**

I couldn't have done it without you guys. My code does exactly what I want it to do, without any problems:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Form_Timer()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblevent (vchrFacility, intWorkCell, intStn, intEventCode) SELECT vchrFacility, intWorkCell, intStn, intEventCode FROM excelTblEvent WHERE dtmInsertedTime > DLookup('Last', 'LastQuery')"
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE LastQuery, excelTblEvent SET LastQuery.Last = excelTblEvent.dtmInsertedTime"
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the errors that you receive?

Comment: I receive a different error every time I modify the code. For the code above, I get a run-time error 3061 (Too few parameters. Expected 1). My research showed its due to an error in the Query, so I got rid of the where portion of the query and was stuck with run-time error 3155 (ODBC--insert on a linked table failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access' db engine will complain about that `INSERT` statement.  Examine the `SELECT` part of the statement:

```sql
SELECT vchrFacility, intWorkCell, intStn, intEventCode
from excelTblEvent
where dtmInsertedTime > LastQuery.Last
```

The `WHERE` clause references a data source, `LastQuery`, which is not mentioned in the `FROM` clause.  That can't work.  We would need to know more about `LastQuery`, but as a wild guess perhaps this might work ...

```sql
WHERE dtmInsertedTime > DLookup("Last", "LastQuery")
```

If Access complains about the `UPDATE` statement, re-build it in the query designer.  After you get it working there, adapt your VBA code to use the same working SQL.

Comment: That seems to quiet down the errors quite a bit. The form loads without error, but doesn't seem to do anything despite me adding new records. I'll take your advice and work with the query designer until it becomes functional. Thank you.

Comment: The form Timer event can be tricky.  After you have the queries working correctly in the designer, test your VBA code first in another procedure, like the click event of a command button.  Set a break point and step thru the code line by line with F8 to see what is (or isn't) happening at each step.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the code working exactly as I wanted. My OP edit shows my final code.

Comment: Yes, congrats.  I'll suggest you move the solution from the question to an answer.  When the system allows, you can accept that answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

A note from the Database.Execute Method help section says,

> ODBCDirect workspaces are not supported in Microsoft Office Access 2007. Use ADO if you want to access external data sources without using the Microsoft Access database engine.

You may have to go this route.

Comment: Ah, well I guess it's time to learn ADO! Thanks for your help =)